# How to upload file in angular 4 from a component along with user detail?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-file-upload

I am making a solution page where the user will upload a file to the node backend server. The Solution component will pass the user detail and file, to the service where I want to post request to backend node server a file along with Loggedin user details.

I have tried ng2-file-uploader. But it uploads file only to a specific api route any idea how i can pass user detail along with it?

html for file Upload

```
<label class="file-upload">Upload File
      <input type="file" class="form-control-file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" placeholder="Upload file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx">
</label>
```

component.ts

```
 URL = 'http://localhost:3000/solution';
 username;
 uploader: FileUploader = new FileUploader({url: this.URL});
```

Comment: Uploading the image separately from the user data is pretty standard now unless you want to use old school formdata which I wouldn't recommend. Standard now is to upload the image to your api which returns your files URL on the server and then use that string in your objects JSON :)

Comment: If the user is logged in as you describe him or her, then you don't need to send the details along with the file. Just attach your authorization token as a header as you normally would.